# Open newly created webpage in php

Tags: php, html

I want to create a new webpage using php.  Then after I create the page I would like to open the page in a browser.  I have the create part (create file) down and the delete file, but how do I (can I?) open the webpage from my php created page that has confirmation message?

To clarify,  I have created an html page that asks the user to enter information to create a web page. I ask the name of the webpage, extension type, and a text box for content. I then give them 3 buttons - Create page, view page, delete page. If the user selects Create, I then run a php page that creates the file for the webpage and displays a message that the web page was created.

So, my question is how do I either return to the html page to allow the user to select view webpage(which does not require php) or to allow the user to select to view the webpage from the "Confirmation" page which is php?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score -1):

You can alter the header file to do this, and some people may suggest this, but I've found that this causes issues without knowing more code that's been written before or afterwards.

I recommend that you use JavaScript to change the location of the page and simply place an "onclick" or "onsubmit" call to the below function on the button that creates the page.

```
<script>
function createAndRedirect(){
var x = document.getElementById("#idOfInputWhereWebPageIsSet");
var y = x.value;

// You can add an alter confirmation message here.
// alert("Web Page Created!"); Remove the comment slashes for a basic confirmation alert.
location.replace(y);
}
</script>
```